# ...Does the new data indicate a departure from previous admission rates?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

> Previous enrollment records at a large university indicate that of the
>   total number of persons who apply for admission, 60% are admitted
>   unconditionally, 5% are conditionally admitted,and the remainder are
>   refused admission. Of 500 applicants to date for next year, 329 were
>   admitted unconditionally, 43 were conditionally admitted, and the
>   remainder were not admitted. Do the data indicate a departure from
>   previous admission rates? Test using $\alpha=0.05$

I'm guessing we're supposed to use a Pearson chi square test for independence.

Skipping the hypothesis statements, and straight to the calculaton for the value of $\chi^2$ I tried:$\newcommand{\obs}{\operatorname{obs}}$

$$\chi^2=\sum\limits^3_{i=1}\frac{(\obs_i-\hat{E}(\obs_i))^2}{\hat{E}(\obs_i)} \\= \frac{(329-329(0.6))^2}{329(0.6)}+\frac{(43-43(0.05))^2}{43(0.05)}+\frac{(128-128(0.35))^2}{128(0.35)} = 1018.4$$

$\obs$ = observed value.

The test statistic seems too large to be correct. So what did I do wrong?

Comment: I think you just made an error regarding your $E_{i}$ values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick look. Your statistic is:

$$\chi^{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{3}\frac{(O_{i}-E_{i})^{2}}{E_{i}}$$

For $i=\{1,2,3\}$, your values should be:

$$O_{i}=\{329,43,128\}$$

and

$$E_{i}=\{0.6\times 500,0.05\times 500,0.35\times 500\}=\{300,25,175\}$$

Your resulting statistic should be:

$$\chi^{2}=26.8520$$

Essentially, your expected number $E_{i}$ should be:

$$E_{i}=p_{i}N$$

where $N$ is your sample size.